# get the null,blank value from the table

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5

I want to get the value which is [null],blank or space from the field 'category_type' from the table
I want to get fetch the [null],blank,'Uncategorized' or space in category_type.
Now I can able to get only blank value .need to get null value too.how to get the null value  field also in postgres db in laravel query.

I have the created the variable `$category=[]`

```
if(in_array('Uncategorized',$category)){
          $category[]='';    
        $category[]='-';                  
        $category[]=' ';                  
        $category[]=null;                 
     }
 $table=DB::('category')->where('category.category_type',$category)->pluck('name')->toArray();
```

Comment: Try `whereIn()` and `whereNull`.

Comment: This topic might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40657940/laravel-eloquent-wherein-with-null

Answer (score 0):

you can add `whereNull()` to check for null values and `whereIn` to check an array of values:

```
if(in_array('Uncategorized',$category)){
        $category[]='';    
        $category[]='-';                  
        $category[]=' ';                                   
}

$table = DB::('category')->whereNull('category.category_type')
           ->whereIn('category.category_type', $category)
           ->pluck('name')
           ->toArray();
```

or

```
$table = DB::('category')->whereNull('category.category_type')
           ->orWhereIn('category.category_type', $category)
           ->pluck('name')
           ->toArray();
```